# How do I connect to local cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a cassandra db running locally.  I can see it working in Ops Center.  However, when I open dev center and try to connect I get a cryptic "unable to connect" error.

How can I get the exact name / connectionstring that I need to use to connect to this local cassandra db via dev center?

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using?

Comment: What is the value of `listen_address` in your cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Does 'cqlsh' work on your terminal?

Answer (score 3):

The hostname/IP to connect to is specified in the `listen_address` property of your cassandra.yaml.If you are connecting to Cassandra from your localhost only (a sandbox machine), then you can set the `listen_address` in your cassandra.yaml accordingly:

```
listen_address: localhost
```

When you start Cassandra, you should see lines similar to this either in STDOUT or in your system.log (timestamps removed for brevity):

```
Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042...
Binding thrift service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9160
Listening for thrift clients...
```

These lines indicate which address you should be using to connect to your cluster.  The first way to test your connection, is with `clqsh`.  Note that cqlsh will connect to "localhost" by default.  If you are connecting to a host/IP other than localhost, then you will need to specify it on the command line.

```
$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0-rc5-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

If this works, then you should also be able to connect (and test) from DataStax Dev Center (also on your local machine) by defining a connection to localhost, like this:

[image]

At this point, you should be able to connect via your application code (Java CQL3 driver shown):

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build();
Metadata metadata = cluster.Metadata;
Console.WriteLine("Connected to cluster: " + metadata.ClusterName.ToString());
Session session = cluster.connect();
```